# Insert or Remove randomly

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a series of characters such as "ABCVABVCCAVB". I wish to randomly remove or insert character.  I could make to remove case like deleting all A, or B,... but I wish to remove or insert only 1 character.

I used this, but this gives back the input...

```
StringDelete["ABCVABVCCAVB", RandomChoice[{"A,B,C,V"}, 1]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have just one, long string in the RandomChoice instead of 4 separate characters.

Comment: Do you say this? StringDelete[{"A,B,C,V"}, RandomChoice[{"A,B,C,V"}, 1]]
I tried, than output is empty...

Comment: How is adding supposed to work? Add one character at the end or at a random position?

Comment: Thank you for all help. The meaning is at any random place, anywhere in the serie.

Comment: @JohnG No, `{"A,B,C,V"}` ==> `{"A", "B", "C", "V"}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are planning to use this for, but here is one way to randomly change elements of the string:

```
str = "ABCABCQBCA";
chars = Flatten[{"", Characters[str]}];
StringReplace[str, RandomChoice[chars] -> RandomChoice[chars], 1]
```

Comment: This does not add or delete characters in the string as required in the OP.

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries Yes it does add/delete... when the "" is chosen it removes or adds, depending on wether it's chosen in the first or second...

Comment: I don't see an empty string among the possible choices. What do I seem to miss?

Comment: @ Sjoerd C. de Vries -- sorry -- a copy paste error on my part. I've got the right `chars` now.

Comment: OK, that should work indeed. +1. One issue remaining is that it only deletes the first matching character and only inserts at the first position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
vvec = {a, w, a, k, b, c, e, t, w, a, b};
position = RandomInteger[{1, Length[v]}]
wvec = Delete[vvec, position];
MatrixForm[vvec]
MatrixForm[wvec]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringJoin@Delete[#, RandomInteger[{1, Length@#}]] & @ Characters["ABCVABVCCAVB"]
```

$\ $`"ABCVABVCAVB"`

```
StringJoin@
   Insert[#, RandomChoice[DeleteDuplicates@#], 
    RandomInteger[{1, Length@#}]] & @ Characters["ABCVABVCCAVB"]
```

$\ $`"ABCVABVACCAVB"`

Answer (score 0):

```
StringDrop[#, {RandomInteger[{1, StringLength@#}]}] &@"ABCDEF"
StringInsert[#, RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"]],
   RandomInteger[{1, StringLength@#}]] &@"ABCDEF"
```